# power source unit for two devices

Tags: power-supply, energy

I have two boards that need 2.5A each and 12V for input. I do have a cable to split the DC, like this one http://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/sunrisebfd/product-detailBoCnNuHKlPWh/China-5-Way-DC-Power-Splitter-Cable-DC03-.html

Questions:

1) to provide energy to both (or more) boards, should I look for a PSU that provides me a 2.5A output or a N * 2.5A output (where N is the number of boards that I want to plugin)?

2) If N * 2.5A, there is a problem with a PSU that outputs 10A, but just 2 boards are connected to it?

Comment: If each board needs (takes) 2.5A then you need to provide that for each board (i.e. N*2.5)

Comment: Also that's a decent amount of current, you might want to check with the manufacturer that it will handle 5A (or make your own cable).

Comment: and why do I received -1?

Comment: @VP. maybe because it's a very basic question, showing little research effort, largely answered by the very first question under the "frequent" section.

Comment: @PhilFrost well, then should close it it as I did with your useless answer ;-)
Anyway, you could just link the link to the frequent questions.. would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electric current is roughly analogous to volume of water flowing per unit time in pipes. Voltage is roughly analogous to water pressure in pipes.

If you have N showers that each need 2.5 litres or water per minute, how many litres per minute do you need supplied from the building's water supply?

---

Update re voltage

The "upstream" water supply is sized to provide for thousands of households, then your shower's don't present an appreciable load on the water company's infrastructure. They probably have a reservoir capable of providing many thousands of litres a minute.

In this case your N concurrently operating showers won't cause a noticeable pressure reduction in the pipes supplying you and your neighbours.

- *Your devices ("boards") won't experience a noticeable drop in voltage if the supply is more than adequate to the task*

Lets say your household water pipes are narrow. In that case the pressure will drop (due to frictional forces of the water in the pipe, - which are proportional to some function of the flow rate, plus other factors)

- *Unavoidable resistance in your wiring and supply components can cause a noticeable drop in voltage when significant current is drawn.*

Obviously you could deal with this by installing a pump that keeps the pressure up

- *A good voltage regulator can prevent significant drops in voltage as higher currents are drawn*

Supposing you supply your showers water from a small tank on your roof (which you refill by hand). In that case, the pressure will drop as the tank empties and the head of water is reduced.

- *Batteries drop in voltage a bit as they become exhausted*

Comment: if you want to go to this direction, explaining it doing analogies, then you should explain as well why Voltage don't change.

Comment: @VP. Your question didn't ask about voltage (or resistance, capacitance etc), so I didn't have any desire to over-complicate the answer. I'll update the answer to address your new question but please don't get into the habit of shifting the goal posts ;-)

Comment: no you don't have to. I know the answer. What I wanted to point is a problem with incomplete analogies. Your answer is clear to me.

Comment: anyway, now its an aswesome answer :)

Comment: "Obviously you could deal with this by installing a pump that keeps the pressure up" A pump, as well as an ordinary voltage regulator, can't tell that the voltage is being dropped before reaching the load, and can not correct for this situation. Most pumps and voltage regulators only regulate the pressure/voltage at the regulator, not the load. There are pumps and voltage regulators that have remote pressure/voltage sensing devices designed to carry small currents to address this problem, but they are not common.